# Particular Solution of Recurrence Equation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

Given:
$S_{n+2} = 13S_{n+1} + 48S_n$ for $\forall n \in N$
I've found the General Solution which is $S_n = A16^n - B3^n$

I don't quite understand how to find the particular solution where $S_0 = 1$ and $S_1=5$. So my question is how do I find the particular solution of this recurrence equation?

Comment: There are no terms except the $S_m$ terms, so there is no "particular solution". All you do now is find $A,B$ by setting $S_0=1,S_1=5$.

Comment: @almagest How would I go about doing that?

Comment: The general solution is not quite right, if should be $A\cdot 16^n+B\cdot (-3)^n$.

Comment: With difficulty since your solution is slightly wrong. It should be $(-3)^n$

Comment: If you correct for that you should get $A=\frac{8}{19},B=\frac{11}{19}$.

Comment: ah! Much thanks. It just clicked. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

$$
S_0 = A - B=1\\
S_1=16A-3B=5
$$

Now solve that system of equations for $A$ and $B$.